# Ajax in amasty layered navigation dont work

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter, magento2.3

Ajax in amasty layered navigation dont work  with my claue theme. Without ajax - working fine.
Then I click on checkbox or another element , page reloaded without filters. 
In store configurations ajax - on .
In console - no errors .
I'm try to debug, but still no luck.
Magento 2.3 , Amasty/shopby latest version, installed by ssh/ftp
Mb someone have the same problems? Or you have ideas or same practice , pls share your idea here , all answers - vote up :)

Comment: did you found any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at this post I made:

[Magento 2 layered navigation Ajax jquery problem](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263899/magento-2-layered-navigation-ajax-jquery-problem/264647#264647)

It will solve your problem.